# My hats are gone

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

My 8 new hats are gone. I have got some at work but at home on my private pc is nothing to see about the hats. What's going on?

[image: No hats to see]

---

[image: and here too]

Comment: Which site? On SO you've still 8 http://stackoverflow.com/users/995926/rekire

Comment: Can people see them if not logged in?

Comment: On SO and meta.SO. That means I can see on http://winterba.sh/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com that they are not really away but I cannot see that they exists on this computer. I tried also to relogin.

Comment: On meta.SO you've indeed only 1. Did you expect that all the 8 hats on SO also applies on meta.SO? In any way, I don't see any problem. Perhaps your computer is blocking some JS code responsible for the hats?

Comment: No I don't I mean SO looks for me on this computer like yesterday without any hints that the hats may exists.

Comment: Did you click "Winter Bash" at the top and remind the site that you love hats?

Comment: I added screenshots.

Comment: Bingo it was noscript. Sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use NoScript on the affected machine, you'll have to set it to allow `winterba.sh`.