# Can I get hats back?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My hats are gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159422/my-hats-are-gone)

All of the sudden today, the Winter Bash link is gone for me!  I don't remember clicking "I hate hats" last night, but I suppose I must have accidentally.  Is there any way to get this feature back, or is it now gone forever?

Comment: have you tried to login into http://winterba.sh/ ?

Comment: Are you using a different machine? At a different location? It seems some problems occur if JS is disabled or if winterba.sh is blocked. I can see hats at home, but no hats at work (where I can't connect to winterba.sh).

Comment: @Jim: spot on! I use NoScript with block by default at work and winterba.sh wasn't allowed. Allowing it gave me back my hats.

Comment: I can see your hats on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @loler I can attest it works without being logged specifically into winterba.sh.

Comment: I almost clicked the hate button too, but in my defense my Watson was covering my entire head at the time. I see your hats on SO, do you not see the Winter Bash icon at all next to your inbox now?

Comment: sorry but it requires **200 million unicorn dollars** ... just click on hat link in your profile .. and it click on hat you want and it will appear again

Comment: My work has blocked winterba.sh.  :(  Sad day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probable that (if you are using a different machine or browsing from a different location, such as at work today vs. at home yesterday) scripts are being blocked. If you want to see hats, make sure scripts are allowed, and that winterba.sh is not blocked.

Comment: This must be it.  My work has blocked winterba.sh.  :(