# What's going on with my stackoverflow winterbash link?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, winter-bash-2012, google-chrome

My winterbash on top navigation is not found at all. Already <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and restarting my chrome.

[image]

Comment: Check that you can actually access http://winterba.sh.

Comment: Did you accidentally turn it off? *None* of the Winter Bash stuff is showing up on your profile in that screenshot.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159613/no-hats-in-profile-on-so-despite-opting-in.

Comment: did you perhaps click "i hate hats" ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I clicked on "I hate hats" but it still appears on the top.

Comment: What's going on with my stackoverflow T_________T

Comment: Are you [using NoScript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159422/131713), perhaps?

Comment: @PopularDemand Indeed, with NoScript you can make it disappear.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that since yesterday winterba.sh is blocked by the proxy my company uses. In my case it is Bluecoat, which blocks winterba.sh as category "Gaming".

That could be the issue on your side, too. To determine whether that is the case try to open http://winterba.sh directly.

Comment: ... way to ruin Christmas :(.

Comment: It would take a lot more than some missing hats on my computer at work to ruin my christmas... ;)

Comment: Sorry, I may have had something to do with that. My company's proxy blocks all uncategorized sites, so I submitted a request to categorize it "Computers/Internet" like stackexchange.com... but it seems to have backfired.